# Prefix search names to output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a simple egrep command searching for multiple strings in a text file which outputs either null or a value. Below is the command and the output.

```
cat Output.txt|egrep -i "abc|def|efg"|cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Output is:-

```
xxx
(null)
yyy
```

Now, i am trying to **prefix my search texts** to the output like below.

```
abc:xxx
def:
efg:yyy
```

Any help on the code to achieve this or where to start would be appreciated.

-Abhi

Comment: Show some sample input and your corresponding desired output.

Comment: Did your `output.txt` by any chance contain the same values as what you're trying get back ?  Are you trying to reverse the process ?  By the way, you don't need `cat`; use `egrep -i 'abc|def|efg' Output.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2`

Comment: What's the output before the | cut -d ...

Comment: Consider `sed` instead of `egrep`&`cut`. If you can figure out the right regex to match the prefix and also capture the value, then you can use back-references - eg. `\1:\2` - to give the desired output.

`awk` could no doubt accomplish the same result by more `cut`-like means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not know exactly your input file content (not specified properly in the question), I will put some hypothesis in order to answer your question.

**Case 1: the patterns you are looking for are always located in the same column**

If it is the case, the answer is quite straightforward:

```
$ cat grep_file.in 
abc:xxx:uvw
def:::
efg:yyy:toto
xyz:lol:hey

$ egrep -i "abc|def|efg" grep_file.in | cut -d':' -f1,2
abc:xxx
def:
efg:yyy
```

After the grep just use the cut with the 2 columns that you are looking for (here it is 1 and 2)

**REMARK:**

Do not `cat` the file, `pipe` it and then `grep` it, since this is doing the work twice!!! Your grep command will already read the file so do not read it twice, it might not be that important on small files but you will feel the difference on `10GB` files for example!

**Case 2: the patterns you are looking for are NOT located in the same column**

In this case it is a bit more tricky, but not impossible. There are many ways of doing, here I will detail the `awk` way:

```
$ cat grep_file2.in 
abc:xxx:uvw
::def:
efg:yyy:toto
xyz:lol:hey
```

If your input file is in this format; with your pattern that could be located anywhere:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";ORS=FS}{tmp=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){tmp=match($i,/abc|def|efg/);if(tmp){print $i;break}}if(tmp){printf "%s\n", $2}}' grep_file
2.in                                                                                                                                         
abc:xxx
def:
efg:yyy
```

**Explanations:** 
`FS=":";ORS=FS` define your input/output field separator at `:` Then on each line you define a test variable that will become true when you reach your pattern, you loop on all the fields of the line until you reach it if it is the case you print it, break the loop and print the second field + an EOL char.
If you do not meet your pattern you do nothing.

If you prefer the `sed` way, you can use the following command:

```
$ sed -n '/abc\|def\|efg/{h;s/.*\(abc\|def\|efg\).*/\1:/;x;s/^[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/;H;x;s/\n//p}' grep_file2.in                               
abc:xxx
def:
efg:yyy
```

**Explanations:**

`/abc\|def\|efg/{}` is used to filter the lines that contain only one of the patterns provided, then you execute the instructions in the block. `h;s/.*\(abc\|def\|efg\).*/\1:/;` save the line in the hold space and replace the line with one of the 3 patterns, `x;s/^[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1/;` is used to exchange the pattern and hold space and extract the 2nd column element. Last but not least, `H;x;s/\n//p` is used to regroup both extracted elements on 1 line and print it.

Comment: @debojith456delhi: great that it helped you! Could you put my answer as correct if it worked for you?

Comment: I did click on the large up arrow before adding my last comment. (✓) clicked too now and accepted as solution.. somehow i had missed it..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$ egrep -io "(abc|def|efg):[^:]*" file
```

will print the match and the next token after delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that there are only two fields, that `abc` etc will always match in the first field, and that getting the last match on a line which contains multiple matches is acceptable, a very simple `sed` script could work.

```
sed -n 's/^[^:]*\(abc\|def\|efg\)[^:]*:\([^:]*\)/\1:\2/p' file
```

If other but similar conditions apply (e.g. there are three fields or more but we don't care about matches in the first two) the required modifications are trivial. If not, you *really* need to clarify your question.